# Change password on Palo Alto Networks firewall has no effect

Tags: firewall, palo-alto-networks

By default, the Palo Alto Networks PA-220 ships with superuser name admin / password admin.  I can change these (either via `ssh > set password` or via the Web GUI `Device > Administrators > admin`.  But, the password seems to remain admin.

This is true even if I click Commit on the Web GUI, and it says committed successfully.

(This is a new brand firewall, not even licensed yet.)

Answer (score 0):

The new password must meet these requirements :

> The new password must be a minimum of eight characters and include a
>   minimum of one lowercase and one uppercase character, as well as one
>   number or special character.

https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/pan-os/9-1/pan-os-admin/getting-started/integrate-the-firewall-into-your-management-network/perform-initial-configuration

Additionally, ensure that the new password length do not exceeds 31 characters.

Comment: It's running PAN-OS 8--does that enforce it? And there were no error messages stating "Password doesn't meet requirements".  Would it be silently ignored?

Comment: I've found similar documentation for 8.1, but it isn't clear what the default password complexity requirements are. Silently ignoring an unacceptable password seems highly unlikely, but it would correspond to the behavior you are seeing. You could try a patently invalid password -- "aaa", for example -- and see if it explicitly rejects it.